# Convert ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, generics

If type `B` can be generalised to type `A`, how do I convert a `List<B>` to a `List<A>`? Do I need a loop like:

```
List<A> newList=new ArrayList<A>();
for(B t:oldList) newList.add(t);
```

Edit: I don't know the word for it, but I mean to say an object of type `B` can be casted to an object of type `A` (like `B implements A`).

Edit2: It appears that the constructor also works:

```
List<A> newList=new ArrayList<A>(oldList);
```

However, I wanted a more efficient approach rather than just copying the list.

Comment: You mean `like B extends A` ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ My use case was when B implements A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't since `List<B>` means that it will contain only elements of type B or subtypes. `List<A>` would allow you to add elements of type A as well, which might be dangerous. Hence you shouldn't cast a `List<B>` into a `List<A>`.

If you create a new `List<A>` and put all elements of `List<B>` into it (e.g. using a loop possibly wrapped in a method) it's ok.

One simple way to fill a new list would be the `addAll()` method, e.g.

```
List<A> aList = ...;
List<B> bList = ...;

aList.addAll( bList );
```

Answer (score 2):

As you stated in *comments*, If your `Class B implements Class A`, the below code is perfectly alight.

```
newList.addAll(listofBs);
```

Since every `B` is an `A`, you are allowed to do that.

And yes you need not to have a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Generics does not allow you to directly up cast collection objects.

You can do couple of things:

```
List<B> oldList = new List<B>();
List<? super B> upcastedList = oldList; // No new object created.
```

If you need to cast the list to a specific type (say A), then you have no option than to loop every element and add it to new list (as you have specified in the question).

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with listA being unmodifiable, here's another possible answer (using Ankur's hint):

```
List<B> listB=new ArrayList<B>();
List<A> listA=Collections.unmodifiableList((List<? extends A>)listB);
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be added during creation as well like

```
List<A> newList = new ArrayList<A>(oldList);
```